# Set client side choice field to stored value via JSOM

Tags: javascript, client-object-model

I am using Angular on top of SharePoint for an application. One of the fields I have is a choice column. I am able to get the values and store them in SharePoint/accessible via REST in my create form, but I need to set the choice dropdown to its stored value in an update form. Here is where I populate the dropdown so users have the correct choices in their create form, but how do I set this to a value, such as "Alert" when they open their update form?

Here is my JSOM:

```
// FIELD NAME: EVENT LEVEL
    // Function to return all of the choices from the Event Level
    function getEventLevelChoices() {
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = ctx.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('MyList');
        var field = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle('Event_x0020_Level');
        var choiceField = ctx.castTo(field, SP.FieldChoice);

        ctx.load(field);
        // Call executeQueryAsync and pass in success and failure anonymous functions
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
            // Return array of all of the choices in the choice field
            var distinctChoices = choiceField.get_choices();
            // Since call is asynchronous, call function to interact with the choices
            onFieldLoaded(distinctChoices);
        },
        // This will be called when executeQueryAsync fails
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log(args);
        });
    };
    function onFieldLoaded(choices) {
        // Not called until choices are loaded into distnctChoices array
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.eventLevelChoices = choices;
        });
    };

    // Execute function
    getEventLevelChoices();
```

Here is my HTML

```
 <select class="form-control" id="Event_Level" data-ng-model="vm.selectedEventLevel"
                                data-ng-options="opt as opt for opt in eventLevelChoices" required>
                            <option style="display:none" value="">Select a Level</option>
                        </select>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here, is it to post the "Event_x0020_Level" value when users clicks "create"? Or do you have an existing item, and want to choose correct value in the dropdown when showing the form?

Comment: It's setting the value of the dropdown to a pre-selected choice. I solved it by setting to use REST instead of JSOM.